# Is it better to save a string/array in a column rather than having multiple rows in a table ? Which has better performance

Tags: mysql, database, database-design

This is my table with a small sample data:

```
    orbId  orbPosition  layoutName
    1      6.7         FirstLayout
    2      7.3         FirstLayout
    3      8.4         FirstLayout
    1      5.5         SecondLayout
    2      6.8         SecondLayout
```

I am using SELECT query to fetch everything with WHERE clause on layoutName. Is it better if I save multiple orbs in one rows and have less rows instead for example:

```
  orbId          orbPosition         layoutName
 ["1","2","3"]  ["6.7","7.3","8.4"]  FirstLayout
 ["1","2"]      ["5.5","6.8"]        SecondLayout
```

Let me know pros and cons of both methods and which method is better suitable.

Comment: Better  having multiple rows in a proper  related table

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3653462/is-storing-a-delimited-list-in-a-database-column-really-that-bad/3653574

Answer (score 0):

`If`
you want to update/modify this data you should go with first approach
`else if`
the data is permanent and needs no change and not needed to be queried individually, then second way is better.

Considering that you have fixed setting for a layout and you need not to modify at any time* and you need not to fetch it individually then you **should** go with second approach.

**Update**

For better performance first approach is better as the rows grow, `index` thing will take care of it.

Comment: Well I will need to update it occasionally but I do it by sending a whole string through a webservice in JSON that updates the whole column. for example I can change orbPosition ["6.7","7.3","8.4"] to  ["1.6","1.3","4.4"]  by sending the latter string as "post" data. You still think I should stick with first approach ?

Comment: Bottom line can you explain why should I stick to first approach if I need to update/modify and vice versa ?

Comment: If you are doing it for storing purpose then go with this approach else this approach is not adviced.

Comment: If you want to update the data individually like `["6.7","7.3","8.4"] ["1.6","1.3","4.4"] ` to  (e.g.) `["1.8","7.3","8.4"] ["0.6","1.3","4.4"] `, mean first value, you will have to update whole the string. Also if you want to have first value you will need to get whole the string.

Comment: First comment from @ scaisEdge, clean appraoch would be first one.

Comment: I guess you are doing it for Android application.

Comment: Close. It's actually for a game.

Comment: Select the better approach based on data quantity, quality of the code and ease for you.